# Html div layout with fixed position

Tags: html, css

I rarely do html/css stuff so I'm struggling trying to implement what seems like a pretty basic layout. I have a bunch of div elements stacked vertically as well as centered horizontally across my html page. The problems I'm facing are

a) the top div (orange) is slightly wider than the other divs.

b) I want the top (orange) div to be visible even when scrolling, which currently isn't the case.

Actually, in order to make the top div always visible, I set its corresponding class' position attribute to fixed but it doesn't work since I also have other divs, and their position is set to relative. If I remove the relative position on the other divs, the orange div works as expected but the rest of divs are not horizontally centered anymore.

```css
.fiksan {
  background-color: orange;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 60%;
  left: 20%;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}

.naslov {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: justified;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
}

.elementi {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 650px;
}

.css_elementi {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="fiksan">
</div>

<div class="naslov">

</div>

<div class="elementi">

</div>

<div class="css_elementi">

</div>
```

This is what it looks like now (when scrolling the top div is covered by other divs, and I don't want that)

[image]

Comment: Yup, it was the `position: fixed` combined with `top: 0` that was giving you the issue. The answer below is the fix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position:sticky` might be what you look for : see https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

```css
.fiksan {
  background-color: orange;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 60%;
margin:auto;
 
}

.naslov {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: justified;
  height: 180px; 
}

.elementi {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 650px;
}

.css_elementi {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 400px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="fiksan">
</div>

<div class="naslov">

</div>

<div class="elementi">

</div>

<div class="css_elementi">

</div>
```